# defaultDate/setDate get's text value of first instance of class instead of the one that was clicked

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Relevant js/jQuery:

```
$(".changeDate").on('click',
    function(e) {
        var taskID = $(this).data('json').taskID;
        var dp = $("<input type='text' />").hide().appendTo('body');
        var curDate = $('#task'+taskID).text();
        dp.datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                dateObj = {};
                dateObj['method'] = 'changeDueDate';
                var newDate = $(this).datepicker().val();
                dateObj['newDate'] = newDate;               
                dateObj['taskID'] = taskID;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'editTasks.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: dateObj,
                    success: 
                        function(date) {
                            if(date.status === 'true') {
                                $('#task'+taskID).text(newDate);
                                dp.datepicker( "destroy" );
                                dp.removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');
                                delete curDate;
                            }else{
                                alert(date.error);
                            }
                        },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert("Something is broken. Let an SA know!\n" + 'Status code: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            },
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate: curDate,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showMonths: true,
            showYears: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: 0
        });

    if (dp.datepicker('widget').is(':hidden')) {
        dp.show().datepicker('show').hide();
        dp.datepicker("widget").position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "right top",
            of: this
        });
    } else {
        dp.hide();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Relevant HTML & PHP:

```
<div class="viewContainer">
    <div align="center" class="smallHeader">Tasks</div>
    <div id="ticketTasksError"></div>
    <table style="width:100%">

    <?php 
        $tasks = array();
        while($row = $ticketTasksResults->fetch_assoc()) {
            $note = stripslashes((isset($row["Note"])) ? $row['Note'] : 'Add note');
            $row["Completed"] == 0 ? $dueDate = $row['DueDate'] : $dueDate = 'Completed on: ' . $row['CompletedWhen']; 
    ?>
        <tr bgcolor="#E5E5E5">
            <td class="tableCellBold"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
            <td class="tableCell"><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></td>
            <td class="tableCell" align="center"><a href="" class="changeDate" id="task<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" data-json='{"taskID":<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>}'><?php echo $dueDate; ?></a></td>
            <td class="tableCell" align="center"><a href="" style="font-size:10pt;" id="editTaskLink">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
            <td class="tableCell" colspan="4" style="font-size:13px"><?php echo $row['Note'] == '' ? '<a href="" class="taskNote" data-json="{"taskID":'.$row['ID'].'}">Add Note</a>' : $row['Note']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border: none; font-size: 5px;"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <?php $i++; } ?>

    </table>
    <div id="addTask" align="left">
        <a href="" style="margin-top:5px;font-size:10pt;padding-left:10px;" id="addTaskLink">Add</a>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Everything works great, except for one problem: `setDate` always gets the value of the first member of the `changeDate` class.

Please assume that all of the PHP works as intended. I confirmed that the value of `curDate` did in fact contain the correct value at the time it is constructed with an `alert` right after it's declaration.

Can you spot what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
By reading the document that was linked to me by Jay, I was able to overcome this problem. It was a closure issue AND and html/php issue (quoting inconsistencies).

Thank you Jay! Just by pointing me to the correct documentation you essentially solved my problem.

**Edit 2:** I'd like to post the solution code, but I can't because I do not have enough reputation yet being I am new to the community and I have to wait 8hrs to answer the post.

So for anyone interested Create a function, like so:

```
var getTaskID = function(taskID) {
    var curDate = $('#task'+taskID).text();
    return curDate;
};
```

Then I changd `setDate` to `defaultDate: $(this).data('json').dueDate`

It is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by `Closure` issues. You need to update your function with proper closures. Probably all "not local" variables in datepicker needs to be passed properly. Look here [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: I've read the article and I am now considering it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @LanceShaw I am glad I could lead you into right right direction. I have faced this problem many a times and which is why, at first glance, I could tell it is due to `Closure`. Don't worry about the upvote thing. If you want, I can try regenerating your functions with proper fix in it.